# How Does detail action work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller in which i have some actions. One of these, is the Detail action.
Here:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id) {
    Type x = ReadFromSomewhere(id);
    return View(x);
}
```

I have another action , that after updating the Type x object , it will return the same object again to the Detail action. So:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(Type y)
{
    Some works here...

    return View("Details", y);
}
```

As you can see i don't pass the id to the `return View("Details", y);`
but everythigs work. Why ? I mean, i should return something like this:

```
return View("Details", y.Id);
```

But the `View()` method accepts only object after the name of the view.
So, What kind of magic is this?

Thank you

Comment: If you show the model and you route definitions I can add an answer explaining the 'magic', but in summary, its because your using the default route and you model contains a property `int ID` (the value is added as a route parameter)

Comment: So is the framework "so smart" to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple reason for this. The [`View()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View%28System.String,System.Object%29) method that you are calling is looking for the view name as the first parameter, and the model object as the second.

In order to not have a generic overload of that method, the type that they are looking for is `object`. Since that is the base type of **EVERY** type in .NET, you are able to supply *any* type as the parameter.

You can set your method call up like that, however you would get a run time exception when the Razor engine tries to render your page and it has a different model type than it is expecting.